# Trying to align Shareholic bar in <li>

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am new to website building. Have basic knowledge in programming only. If you headover to www.hum3r.com , you can see a social bar from shareholic which is first of all only showing 80%. What I want to do is align this bar along with the user. The following code i have put in php file.

```
<li class="cosmo-love"><?php like::content($post->ID, 3); ?></li>
<li class="share-1">
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[shareaholic app="share_buttons" id="5457823"]'); ?>
</li>
```

I tried everything in chrome developer tools trying to change height width, etc. Could some one please tell me how to get this in one line. If you need any further info please ask me.

Comment: Thanks Nick I was doing the code edit too

Comment: you can either make your lis [inline-block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) elements or [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) them

Answer (score 1):

Inspect the element shown in the first highlight bellow. And make the change shown in the second highlight (remove `position:relative`):

[image: Please check the image)]

Comment: Both the answers let me see both the things as in the author bar and Shareholic bar. One after the other. What I want is both to be displayed in the same line.

Comment: Please help me out :)